# does the tablesort jquery plugin work in google chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

is there a way i can add a jquery tablesorter plugin so that i sort my table using a google chrome browser this my code in the header file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#soop").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 

</script> 

echo "<table id='soop' border='1' cellpadding='10' >";

    echo " <thead> 
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
</tr> </thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
    {

    echo " <tr>";
    echo '<td><b>' . $row['id'] . '</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>' . $row['first_name'] . '</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>' . $row['last_name'] . '</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>' . $row['address'] . '</b></td>';
    echo '<td><b>' . $row['phone_number'] . '</b></td>';

    echo " </tr>";

    }
     echo "</tbody>";
```

is there a way  of making the tablesort plugin work in google chrome or its just me making errors

Comment: It should work in chrome.

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error? Also, I don't think it matters, but you're missing a closing `</table>` in the code above.

Answer (score -1):

You need provide class name to your table and include the style sheet given in the plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#soop").tablesorter(); 
} 
); 

</script> 

<?php
echo "<table id='soop' class='tablesorter' border='1' cellpadding='10' >";
```

Hope this will help...:)